# Getting Mongoose error on building NestJs project

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have used Mongoose package in my Nest project but when I am trying to build the project using `npm run build`. Then it's throwing below error in my console:

```
node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts:34:15 - error TS2305: Module '"tls"' 
has no exported member 'TLSSocketOptions'.

34 import type { TLSSocketOptions } from 'tls';
```

I have even updated the `mongoose` package to the latest version.Then also I am getting the same error:

Below are my dependencies inside `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@apollo/gateway": "^0.38.0",
    "@google-cloud/translate": "^6.2.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.6",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.6",
    "@nestjs/cqrs": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^8.0.2",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^8.0.6",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.0.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.6",
    "@types/luxon": "^1.15.1",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.25.2",
    "bunyan": "^1.8.12",
    "bunyan-rotating-file-stream": "^1.6.3",
    "connect-redis": "^3.4.1",
    "consul": "^0.40.0",
    "device-detector-js": "^3.0.3",
    "elasticsearch": "^16.2.0",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "graphql": "^14.7.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.4",
    "json-rules-engine": "^3.1.0",
    "kafkajs": "^1.15.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^1.16.0",
    "moneysafe": "^2.2.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.9",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.0",
    "nestjs-i18n": "^8.1.1",
    "node-wit": "^6.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.3.0",
    "ts-morph": "^12.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
 },
"devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.134",
    "@types/node": "^10.7.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.5",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "supertest": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^23.1.3",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.5.0",
    "tslint": "5.11.0"
}
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Add  ‘@types/mongoose’ and ‘@types/mongodb’ dev dependency and try. Looks like your are missing Type definition

Comment: I have added both as dev dependencies but still having the same error.

Comment: On running in dev mode its working no such issue regarding mongo but when I am building then only this error is coming up.

Comment: It seems that you have 2 mongoose ORMs, 1 is from `@nestjs/mongoose` another is just mongoose, I had such a problem with dependency conflict, maybe you can try to install both versions, but compatible with each other

Comment: `@nestjs/mongoose` is already have latest version and I have updated `mongoose` also to `6.3.0` version

Comment: @sohan: this is incorrect, the latest versions of Mongo and Mongoose have types included and don't required a separate package. See :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongodb
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongoose




Digvijay: I have the same issue you have, updating Mongoose to 6.3 (coming from 4). I updated TypeScript as well, that solved some issues, but still get this error. Did you find a fix?

Comment: @Koekenbakker28 I think he is already on latest version of MongoDb and TS

Comment: @Sohan then the suggestion to add the types is obsolete, you don't need the types anymore. I think for this specific case, the fix is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72474645/6557736

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by updating @types/node to the latest version. This specific error message is then fixed!